# FreeBSD on AZURE

Tags: azure, freebsd, network-share

I am testing AZURE with FreeBSD 10.3.
FreeBSD is up and running, configured, can connect remotely to it, but it has limited storage.
I would like to attach another disk / mount point in order to have ~1TB space available for pretty big SVN repo, however I cannot find the way to achieve that.
In the resource groups I have storage account called svn1, and in that storage account I have 4 options: blobs, files, tables and queues.

From what I understand I should then use files, so I created shared file service called sharedfiles with quota set to 1TB.

Now if I click on connect I get:

```
> sudo mount -t cifs //svn1.file.core.windows.net/sharedfiles [mount point] -o vers=3.0,username=svn1,password=[storage account access key],dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

as the linux command to mount that resource.

My questions are

1. How this command can be translated to FreeBSD?

I tried a few different ways based on *mount_smbfs* but non of them was successful.

2. Is this the right way to mount extra volume(s) from AZURE in FreeBSD?
3. I was thinking of starting PostgreSQL DB and ideally I would like to store its data on separate SSD volume / mount point. How to achieve that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like it has to be done in completely different way, i.e. I have to add disk in my VM configuration. After adding disk I found it in dmesg, partitioned it and prepared for normal use

Comment: yup. File storage is meant for SMB shares. Bear in mind that disks can be as up as 1TB and you can only add up to 2 disks per CPU, i.e 2 cores VM may have up to 4TB.

Answer (score -1):

Azure allows you to attach disk to an existing VM. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/attach-disk. You can choose HDD or SSD.
After that, you can use "mount /dev/da2 /mnt/data" to use that disk.

Comment: You should include more information in this answer. Answers on this site are supposed to be useful even if the links they point to are all dead. Links for reference is good, but it is no substitute for writing an answer which can stand on its own.